# django list_filter is not scrollable

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-admin-filters

I have a long list of elements (50 elements) and I wanted to use that as a list_filter in django admin panel. But when I use this list, on very right side where FILTER panel appears I can see only 20 items and it is not scrollable so rest of 30 is hidden. How can I get those 30 items in FILTER section or How scrolling will be possible so that all 50 items can be viewed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom filter for your field and use a dropdown as selector.
I strongly recommend using https://github.com/mrts/django-admin-list-filter-dropdown which already provide a couple of filters.

If you want to create your own:

admin.py

```
from django.contrib.admin.filters import RelatedOnlyFieldListFilter

class RelatedOnlyDropdownFilter(RelatedOnlyFieldListFilter):
    template = 'filters/related_filter.html'

@admin.register(ModelName)
class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   
    list_filter = (      
        ('field', RelatedOnlyDropdownFilter),
    )
```

related_filter.html

```
{% load i18n %}
<script type="text/javascript">var filter_by_select = function(opt) { window.location = window.location.pathname + opt };</script>
<h3>{% blocktrans with title as filter_title %} By {{ filter_title }} {% endblocktrans %}</h3>
<ul class="admin-filter-{{ title|cut:' ' }}">
{% if choices|slice:"4:" %}
    <li>
    <select class="form-control"
        onchange="filter_by_select(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
    {% for choice in choices %}
        <option{% if choice.selected %} selected="selected"{% endif %}
         value="{{ choice.query_string|iriencode }}">{{ choice.display }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
    </li>
{% else %}

    {% for choice in choices %}
            <li{% if choice.selected %} class="selected"{% endif %}>
            <a href="{{ choice.query_string|iriencode }}">{{ choice.display }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}

{% endif %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use this cool third-party.

- [django-admin-autocomplete-filter](https://pypi.org/project/django-admin-autocomplete-filter/)

It's easy to use and user-friendly in case of your problem.

[image]

For example look at this. `models.py`

```
from django.db import models

class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Album(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cover = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, default=None)
```

`admin.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from admin_auto_filters.filters import AutocompleteFilter


class ArtistFilter(AutocompleteFilter):
    title = 'Artist' # display title
    field_name = 'artist' # name of the foreign key field


class ArtistAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['name'] # this is required for django's autocomplete functionality
    # ...


class AlbumAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = [ArtistFilter]

    """
        defining this class is required for AutocompleteFilter
        it's a bug and I am working on it.
    """
    class Media:
        pass

    # ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This gives a Template does not exist error

Comment: @Pradeep I think you forgot to add `'admin_auto_filters'` this line to your `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py` :)

Comment: @Pradeep Please read this [docs](https://pypi.org/project/django-admin-autocomplete-filter/) **Add** `admin_auto_filters` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` inside `settings.py` of your project.